# Knife tool problem

Tags: modeling

The knife tool creates overlapping vertex on a model, this didn't happen in the early of modelling.

Here is the line I created with knife tool
[image]

when you move the edge, you can see, there are new overlapping vertexs ( I moved the edges so you can see them )

[image]

is this a glitch?

Comment: The knife in 2.8 doesn't seem to be as convenient as in 2.7, it's hard to see and no way to see when it sticks to an existing vertex, I hope it will be improved, maybe it needs to be reported?

Comment: Judging by the inconsistent shading and after testing this, it is possible you already had double geometry before applying the kinfe. Could you try Merging (Right click > Merge by distance ) in edit mode and vertex select mode ?

Comment: I searched the other related posts, some said, it is because Blender doesn't support this kind of topology, however, it works most of the times if I use Snap vertex.